# offline_access for page admins

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

According to this facebook article : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/offline-access-removal
  offline_access perm has been removed from FB platform.

And i know that a user has to login again to revalidate access_tokens.
What if i am admin of facebook pages? Do i have to login again and again to revalidate those tokens and call facebook oauth apis to extend expiry of tokens?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate an **Extended Page Token**. Those are valid forever.

Detailed information about Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/